# How to use React ContextAPI in static html file

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have static html file and used umd script like:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

I can use `<MyContext.Provider> and <MyContext.Consumer>`. But unable to use

```
static contextType = MyContext;
```

The output to console.log(this.context) is getting an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running this example from https://medium.com/@muddassirm/react-context-api-made-simple-a778ec819fa7 . This does seem to work !

Code running in Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/A4YCEJR3GvqVgs6X?preview

```js
const Context = React.createContext();

const ContextApp = () => {
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={['THE', 'QUICK', 'BROWN', 'FOX', 'JUMPS', 'OVER', 'THE', 'LAZY', 'DOG']}>
        <CustomComponent/>
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}

class CustomComponent  extends React.Component {    
  render(){
      let context = this.context      
      return(<div>{context.map((item) => <li>{item}</li>)}</div>)
  }  
}

CustomComponent.contextType = Context

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <ContextApp />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: MyComponentClass.contextType = MyContext; //giving error Cannot set property 'contextType' of undefined

Comment: ok. When  I simply write it down after the class definition. it is not giving any error but still empty

Comment: Better still use this html structure - https://plnkr.co/edit/A4YCEJR3GvqVgs6X

Comment: can we use consumer in child and grandchild components also. In child component I have used consumer and in grandchild I was to use this.context. Is it possible

Comment: Yes I have updated plunker to use Consumer https://plnkr.co/edit/A4YCEJR3GvqVgs6X

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209848/discussion-between-muddassir-and-dhiraj900).

Comment: Thanks @muddassir. Not sure but it was started working with this.context automatically. May be cache or other issue.